# Full width buttons on desktop web application

Tags: forms, buttons

I have a design for a form with a full width button, this is a desktop web application and for context it is an interactive shell/terminal that lest you submit API requests. It essentially looks like this, this is the exact sizing of terminal and button (scaled to fit on this page), button is 1384px x 50px. The terminal window on top, the button below.

[image]

Looking for any feedback if this is good UX or not or any research around full width buttons on desktop. My first impression is that it doesn't really look like a button, maybe more like a banner, so users might actually ignore it.

Comment: "My first impression is that it doesn't really look like a button, maybe more like a banner, so users might actually ignore it." My point of view as well...